# I'm trying to parse data from a webpage using the importXML function but the data doesn't have a class

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to preface with I am a complete newbie to coding of all kinds. I usually spend 10x more time using google to try to automate something than it would have taken me to do it manually. I found a Google Sheet online that looks for the price of a MTG trading card from a specific web page.

This is the working function I am using in the google sheet.
`=Index(IMPORTXML('Price Links Sale'!A13, "//span[@class='price price--withoutTax']"),1)`

Where 'Price Links Sale' is the sheet that contains all of the URL's for each card I'm looking up.
Example:
https://www.facetofacegames.com/assassins-trophy-guilds-of-ravnica/
This pulls the price for a non-foil near mint card. Perfect. Works great.

I wanted to add another column on my google sheet that checks the quantity in stock.

What I tried was

`=Index(IMPORTXML('Price Links Sale'!A13, "//span[@class='data-product-stock']"),1)`

What I realized is that span in this case doesn't have a class. I tried this as well as a few other things with no success. One of them being
`=Index(IMPORTXML('Price Links Sale'!A13, "//span[not@class='data-product-stock']"),1)`

I have no clue what I am doing, I'm just giving it the ole' college try. Is this something incredible simple?

Each web page using the radio buttons to check the price for foil, non-foil, near mint condition and played condition. Is it possible to use excel functions to use the radio buttons to grab those prices as well if I tell the function I'm looking for foil prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value `0` from `<span data-product-stock>0</span>` using IMPORTXML.
- The URL you want to use is `https://www.facetofacegames.com/assassins-trophy-guilds-of-ravnica/`.

In this case, I think that `data-product-stock` is the attribute which has no value. So how about the xpath of `//span[@data-product-stock]`? The formula is as follows.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span[@data-product-stock]")
```

- The URL is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

### Added:

#### Pattern 1:

For example, when you want to retrieve the values of `0` from `<span data-product-stock>0</span>` and `<div class="card-stock"><span>0</span> In Stock</div>`, you can also use the xpath of `//div[contains(@class,'stock')]/span[1]`.

Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[contains(@class,'stock')]/span[1]")
```

Result:

[image]

- In this case, 10 items are retrieved.

#### Pattern 2:

For example, when you want to retrieve `18` of `18 in stock`, how about the following sample formula?

Sample formula:

```
=JOIN("",IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//script"),"stock"":(\d+),")),""))
```

- In this case, it seems that the value cannot be directly retrieved. So in this sample formula, the value is retrieved from the Javascript.

Result:

[image]

Comment: At the time of writing this, there are 18 in stock, and I am getting a result of zero, just as you are. But I think you're pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Brendin Lloyd Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, I would like to confirm whether my understanding of your question is correct. I understood that you want to retrieve the value `0` from `<span data-product-stock>0</span>` using IMPORTXML. Is my understanding correct? When I saw the HTML of the URL, there is only one value of `<span data-product-stock>0</span>`. So I cannot understand about `At the time of writing this, there are 18 in stock, and I am getting a result of zero, just as you are.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Brendin Lloyd Now, about `18 in stock`, I thought that I might be able to understand it. So I added 2 more sample formulas in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Pattern 2 is exactly what I need, thank you so much!!
I was reading ImportXML tutorials late last night and throughout the day and I thought I could figure it out by myself. I never would have gotten close to the formula you used in pattern 2.